# Combining DocumentDB MaxItemCount with custom select statement

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to combine custom select statements (within DocumentDB) and having MaxItemCount work at the same time.

An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
 var itemList= DocClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyEntity>(
                     collection.SelfLink, 
                     new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5 })
                     .Select(m =>
                                    new {
                                        MyProperty1 = m.Property1,
                                        MyProperty2 = m.Property2
                                    });
```

In the above case, MyEntity might have several properties, but I only want to return the first 2 properties (and save on execution duration/traffic etc).

This works fine, but the MaxItemCount is being ignored. No matter what I put there, I get the entire collection back.

Now, if I modify the query to be something like:

```
IDocumentQuery<MessageEntity> query =             
                        DocClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MessageEntity>               
                        (collection.SelfLink, new FeedOptions{MaxItemCount=5}).AsDocumentQuery();


var myTask = query.ExecuteNextAsync<MessageEntity>();
```

Now, with this second case, the MaxItemCount is obeyed (I only get 5) but I cannot seem to have a custom Select statement limiting which properties to return.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a known limitation?

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 0):

The query produces an IQueryable object, which you generally to an AsEnumerable() on to get something you can enumerate over using a ToList or ToArray or something like this.

This will continue fetching results in blocks of MaxItemCount until there are no more results (continuation == String.Empty)

If you don't want to do this, and control the paging, then use the AsDocumentQuery() extension and fetch each page manually with ExexcuteNextAsync() as you indicated.

So, you could do;

```
        var q = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5 })
                   .Where(f => f.Id == "AndersenFamily" || f.Address.City == "NY")
                   .Select(f => new { Name = f.LastName, City = f.Address.City })
                   .AsDocumentQuery();
```

and then continue to use query.ExecuteNextAsync() to get each page as you are doing.

Comment: If I try that with an anonymous type I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery<XXXX.datatypes.MessageEntity>'.       if I try it with the real document entity then I get back the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<XXXX.datatypes.MessageEntity>' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery<XXXX.datatypes.MessageEntity>'.   I can't cast from one to the other surely? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ken - does this work consistently for you?  I am using MaxItemCount and

Comment: Ken - does this work consistently for you?  In a CreateDocumentQuery I am using MaxItemCount and then HasMoreResults and ExecuteNextAsync - which has been described in other posts.  My issue is that sometimes - particularly after a large update to the DocumentDB - looping through every document has somewhat random results with up to half the documents being ignored.  This ONLY happens if I include a SQL query in the query setup.  If I allow all fields to come back it works 100%.  But this is inefficient as I am exporting a couple of columns only. Any experience in this issue?

Comment: @KenFaulkner please mark as answer if it helped you

Comment: @smulldino please create a new question for this as your issue is different to Ken's original issue.